# Can't Find Rx Dump() Method

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I've seen lots of answers on here and in various posts and tutorials on other sites where the `Dump()` method is used on an `IObservable<T>` sequence. However, when I try to use it, I get a `... does not contain a definition for 'Dump' and no extension method for 'Dump' ... Cannot resolve symbol 'Dump'` warning from the compiler. Has it been removed from Rx, or am I missing a library?

Comment: `Dump()` is an extension method that exists in [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/)

Comment: This sounds a lot like the code sippets you saw were copied from LINQPad. LINQPad brings a `.Dump()`-extension method to output the contents of the object into its output window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes I agree with the comments that it exists in LinqPad, however you may write your own as in http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/07_Aggregation.html

```
public static class SampleExtentions
{
    public static void Dump<T>(this IObservable<T> source, string name)
    {
        source.Subscribe(
           i=>Console.WriteLine("{0}-->{1}", name, i), 
           ex=>Console.WriteLine("{0} failed-->{1}", name, ex.Message),
           ()=>Console.WriteLine("{0} completed", name));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Recommend to use LINQPad related nuget package (LINQPad officially provided), then you can use `Dump()` method of it.

[image: LINQPad]

#### For .NET core:

- Install LINQPad.Runtime

#### For .NET framework 4 etc.

- Install LINQPad

Sample code:

```cs
using System;
using LINQPad;
namespace csharp_Dump_test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                dosome();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.Dump();
            }
        }

        private static void dosome()
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable.");
        }
    }
}
```